# files found with path 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so' from inputs

Tags: android, c++, shared-libraries

`2 files found with path 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so' from inputs:

- C:\Users\fengguangbo.gradle\caches\transforms-3\b8b79ba0a0c74f3b23765edff74e12e0\transformed\jetified-react-native-0.67.0\jni\arm64-v8a\libc++_shared.so
- C:\Users\fengguangbo.gradle\caches\transforms-3\15e56da945c5afe212d84666ef25ebb3\transformed\jetified-base-7.5.8\jni\arm64-v8a\libc++_shared.so
  If you are using jniLibs and CMake IMPORTED targets, see
  [https://developer.android.com/r/tools/jniLibs-vs-imported-targets`](https://developer.android.com/r/tools/jniLibs-vs-imported-targets%60)

`packagingOptions { pickFirst 'lib/*/libc++_shared.so' }`

But I do not know which lib will been selected, react-native or others.
Who know which version with "libc++_shared.so" in react-native?
And when hanppend this quession, how to fixed it andd running well?

Comment: Have you read https://developer.android.com/r/tools/jniLibs-vs-imported-targets as printed in the output?